# How to split user input and assign values to each group python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, assign

Im trying to create a roman numeral calculator, and to do so I want to split the user input into 3 sections left, operation, and right such that in XV + L the "XV" would be held by the left, the "+" would be held under op and the right would hold "L"

I know that I can split the input using a right split like below but I just get

X

V

+

L

how would I assign right, op, and left values to the output?

```
userinput = input("What do you want to be calculated? ")


for char in userinput:

    char = s.rsplit(";", 3)

    print(char)
```

Comment: Where the semicolon comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> userinput = input("What do you want to be calculated? ")
What do you want to be calculated? XV + L
>>> left,op,right = userinput.split()
>>> left
'XV'
>>> op
'+'
>>> right
'L'
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense, however when i print left it repeats 7 times

Comment: 7 times? how? show your code.

Comment: userinput = input("What do you want to be calculated? ")


    for char in userinput:


        left, op, right = userinput.split()

        print(left)

Comment: you don't need to use the for loop. Just unpacking would be fine. See my update.